# Angular 1.4.8 inner ng-show cause an error when used in custom directive root element

Tags: angularjs-directive, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I got an error when i put a nested ng-show attributes for custom directive,
one attribute in the markup of the directive and the second inside the root element of the directive template.

My real scenario are complex so i will simplify it to this example:

> Suppose i have my-custom-directive below which already contains ng-show:

```
<my-custom-directive ng-show="someValue >= 5"></my-custom-directive>
```

> And then the template of 'my-custom-directive' look like this:

```
<div ng-show="options != null">My Custom Directive</div>
```

Those multiple ng-show together cause an error.

if i remove one of them or move the inner ng-show at least one level deeper in it's dom tree the error gone (it's happen when it's location is on the root template element).

this error tested on angular v1.4.8.

Is this angular bug? or there is a reasonable explanation for this behavior?

here is the Plunker example:
http://embed.plnkr.co/ZTZVcfc5bfmjPo9t0Isw

Thank you in advance,

Menachem

Answer (score 0):

Because the directive has `replace: true`it is trying to merge the two ng-show values together resulting in an error. The simplest solution I believe is to just do `replace: false`

Or you can inject the value via isolate scope and use a single ng-show value within the directive. I believe this is considered the cleaner solution.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5oc8c1Hrz8N1F2klCio7?p=info

```
scope: {
  someValue: '=someValue'
}
```